# SharePoint 2010 dynamic dropdowns document library properties

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using SharePoint 2010.
 I have a document library, and when someone uploads an item to that library, they are presented with a form to select properties. I have 4 properties I want them to select (really 6, but the first two are Name and Title). The issue is that these 4 properties depend on each other in this way:

1st property: I use a lookup to offer 4 choices, "A" "B" "C" or "D" in a dropdown.

2nd property: I want to offer the user a choice of 4 items in a dropdown, based on what they chose for the 1st property. (if they chose "A", then offer "1" "2" "3" or "4", if they chose "B" offer "5" "6" "7" or "8", etc.)

3rd property: same thing as above, but now based on what they chose for the 2nd property (if they chose "1", offer "a" "b" "c" or "d", if "5" offer "s" and "t")

4th property: again based on 3rd property.

How can I do this? can I write some sort of custom form that can do this?

Comment: You probably want to check Google and the thousands of articles about it: https://www.google.com/search?q=sharepoint+dropdown+cascading
Then if it doesn't help, you can provide a part of your code.

Comment: I had done those searches, and found several good options that I could understand (I have little javascript experience), but they only worked for 3 level cascading. I ended up writing a ASP page that used the SharePoint object model to do it, then I put that ASP page on SharePoint as a web part, and it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do that, I think you should build your custom form for that(it's great if you already had). In your form, you can use javascript/jquery to adding your logic for above cases. You should add a changed event for the dropdown control. When the value of the dropdown control has changed, you should check your business logic and update the the next property if you want to show.

Comment: I ended up building a ASP page to do it with the SharePoint object model